# C++ Find Entry Point

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Well, i am feeling a little bit foolish asking something like this, but i' have no idea where the main function is in code i got from another person.

It's a pretty large Visual C++ project. So my question is simple, and please forgive me for asking this, but is there an easy way to find the entry point in a c++ solution in visual studio? It may not be called main, because there is a link to MFC tools (so perhaps WinMain).
Thank You!

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `f`, type `main`, `enter` if that fails, then try to debug

Comment: ...only 42 Matching files, how about no?

Comment: that does sound like a small number that you should be able to look through, might still be faster than compiling and starting up the debugger

Comment: you are right, but i think 42 migth be in this case not THE answer ;) i' am looking for an easy way

Comment: If it is a MFC Gui application, instead of searching for `main`, you should then search for `InitInstance`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Debug->Step Into used while you are not debugging should start debugging and will break at the entry point.

Comment: Exactly what i searched for. With ctrl + shift + f i wouldn't had found it

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+, will give you some kind of search for member thing, then you look for your main function and it will possibly give you where it is declared.